# In spree, Is there any possibilities to keep all checkout process steps in a single page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

Is there any in-built feature is there in spree or we only need to customize that?

Answer (score 7):

I recently published a blog post about this topic, hope it helps.

http://nebulab.it/blog/one-page-checkout-with-spree

The approach describes how to:

1. change the checkout/edit.html.erb view to display all relevant checkout steps.
2. add a `:remote => true` to all form_for but the last one.
3. create a js view in checkout/edit.js.coffee which will replace the content of the next step in the right place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's okay to link to external webpages, but you should always provide context and quote the relevant part of the webpage, since external pages occasionally disappear or are temporarily unavailable. See "[How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" in the Help Center.

Comment: @nandhp I've added some context to the answer, I hope it is enough. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this demo to get more details, I think it will useful for you. [link](http://rg-spree-gems-test.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try our the [spree_one_page_checkout gem](https://github.com/RacoonsGroup/spree_one_page_checkout)
But i really don't know if its worked correctly.

Comment: After installing the gem it throws the following error in cart page.
undefined method `spree_user_signed_in?'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own version of that. I don't know of any extensions that offer that support.

Comment: thanks @Ryan Bigg. I'm using the following gem https://rubygems.org/gems/spree_one_page_checkout. But I am getting the following error  "undefined method spree_user_signed_in?" in some pages. If i fix the issues will it work or not?

Comment: I am not in charge of maintaining that extension so I cannot answer that question.